# R How how write a function with ggplot so it changes title and variable at the same time?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data with 5 groups and want to write a function that shows a graph for the specific group (to avoid writing the same code 5 times.
I wanted to have this function in order to have different graphs for different countries. How can I solve this problem?

```
myplot <- function(X) {
ggplot(subset(total.table,Country%in% paste0(X)), aes(x = year, y = percentage.types, fill = Type)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
    # or:
    # geom_bar(position = position_fill(), stat = "identity") 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(subset(total.table,MARKET_AREA_NAME %in% "Finland")$percentage.types, digits=2)*100, "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 4)   +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 30))+
  labs(title = paste0("Production portfolio in", X, ", in% (relative to total production)", sep=""), 
     )}
```

I had the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (55): x, y and fill
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Suggest to do what the error message suggests: run `rlang::last_error()`. This will show the error stack. Without your data it is hard to say what happened. Your easthetics `year`, `percentage.types` or `Type` could be of wrong length. This line looks a little suspect: `subset(total.table,Country%in% paste0(X)` Why use `paste0(X)`?

Comment: I would recommend using `lapply` as described here: https://rpubs.com/paul4forest/ggplot_lapply

Comment: @ Paul van Oppen it says  Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (55): x, y and fill
Backtrace:
 1. (function (x, ...) ...
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 6. ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 7. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 8. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
 9. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)

I put "USA" instead of paste0(USA) it works. I tried to put Country%in% X (function of X) and when put plot(USA) it doesnt work. What instead of paste?

Comment: What are you sending as `X` here?  Pretty sure that this is related to sending a symbol or name of a dataset and using it as a character and vice versa.  For example, `paste(mtcars)` gives you a very different result than `paste("mtcars")`.  To output the name of the dataset `mtcars` as text, you can place it within `expr()` to prevent the evaluation as a name: `paste(expr(mtcars))`.  So, maybe using `paste0(expr(X))` will work when you want to paste the name as a character (and not send to the function the full dataset or column name)?  Hard to say for sure without some of your dataset.